# Persisting redux state vs dynamic urls

Tags: reactjs, web, url, redux

In the app I am working on I have a state that is chosen in a dropdown by the user. I would like this state to still be the same after the user refreshes the page

Two options:

1. Store the state in the url by adding "/:state"

- We must hit the api endpoint again to get the data based on the state. So it is always fresh
- The url can be stored in history and copied/bookmarked
- Everytime the state is changed by the user, the url changes causing a reload of the page

2. Store the state in redux and persist it

- Have to install a package like redux-persist which takes some configuration
- data persists on page reload so we don't need another api call
- data may be outdated and need to be re-pulled

Which option is better? What scenarios break either option?

Answer (score 0):

> Everytime the state is changed by the user, the url changes causing a reload of the page
> If you use something like `react-router`, app doesn't reload each time you change url.

Decision where to store some setting depends on the case. I usually prefer to store in url only things that are related to navigation: changing views/pages, opened modals, search/filters. Usually you want to store it in url when you want this url to be shareable with other users. So it you want to put some dropdown value in url, consider: Do you want browser navigation to change this value? Does this dropdown change some view?

Also, sometimes you have to store this selection on backend. Usually when it is a property of some entity or it's a setting. You have to consider whether you want this dropdown's value to be shared between multiple sessions on different devices.